# Read data from damaged media

Tags: file, disk, recovery

Is it possible to read damaged media (cd, hdd, dvd,...) even if windows explorer bombs out?

What I mean to ask is, whether there is a set of APIs or something that can access the disk at a very low level (below explorer?) and read whatever can be retrieved even if it is only partial, especially if you can still see the file is there from explorer, but can't do anything with it because it is damaged somehow (scratch on cd, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with Windows Explorer is that it doesn't support resuming copying after a read error. Most superficially scratched CDs, for example, will fail on different areas of the disk every time you eject and reinsert them.

Therefore, with a utility that supports resuming copy operations, it is possible to read the entire contents of a damaged CD with by doing "eject/reload/resume" a few times.

In fact, this is what a [utility I wrote](http://aib.ftuff.com/get.php?file=filecopy.exe) does, and I've never needed anything fancier to read scratched disks. (It simply uses ReadFile and WriteFile.)

One step lower would be opening the raw partition (i.e. disk image) by passing a string such as "\.\F:" (note: slashes are literal here) to CreateFile. It would allow you to read raw sectors from a drive, but reconstructing files from that data would be hard.

In fact, the "\.\" syntax allows you to open devices in the "\GLOBAL??" branch of the Windows Object Manager namespace as if they were files. It's not unlike calling dd with /dev/x as a parameter. There is also a "\Device" branch, but that's only accessible via DeviceIoControl() (i.e. ioctl()), meaning there's no simple ReadFile()/WriteFile() interface.

Anything lower level than that would be device-specific, I guess; like reading raw CD-ROM data (including ECC bits) the way some CD-burning programs do. You'd have to do some research on the specific media (CD, flash, DVD) and what your hardware allows you to do on them.

Note: The backslashes seem to get lost on the way to the web page; you need to pass "backslash backslash dot backslash DeviceName" to CreateFile. You need to escape them, too, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it, do it from the Linux side - see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/monkeycity/ opensource

or ready made app and freeware too: http://www.theabsolute.net/sware/dskinv.html

Answer (score 1):

the first step is [dd_rescue](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/).  After that, you're free to try anything to reconstruct the data.

Answer (score 1):

And there's [GNU **`ddrescue`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/)

> GNU ddrescue is a data recovery tool. It copies data from one file or block device (hard disc, cdrom, etc) to another, trying to rescue the good parts first in case of read errors.

Make sure to use the 3-arg version ([manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)):

```
ddrescue [options] infile outfile [mapfile]
```

That is, do use a **`mapfile`** even if it's optional, because:

> If you use the mapfile feature of ddrescue, the data is rescued very efficiently, (only the needed blocks are read). Also you can interrupt the rescue at any time and resume it later at the same point. The mapfile is an essential part of ddrescue's effectiveness. Use it unless you know what you are doing.

And it's also included in Cygwin and Homebrew.

Comment: A late addition, coz I just had a great success using `ddrescue`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what layer exists between Windows Explorer and the Win32 APIs.  You can try to write a program with the Win32 File I/O stuff.  If that doesn't work, then you have to write your own device driver to get any lower.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck from the linux side, or using BartPE (http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), but just seeing the file doesn't always mean the file is going to be recoverable, whether you're trying from Windows or Linux.  You're best bet might be to use a trial of a recovery program.

Answer (score 0):

I have had two disks start to disintegrate on me. From the pattern of unreadable sectors I think they had internal flaking of their emulsion. WinXP Explorer just threw up its hands and said the drive didn't even exist.

In both cases I used "GetDataBack for NTFS" from Runtime Software (http://www.runtime.org/). You can download a free trial which will show you what you *could* get back if you paid for it. When I bought it it was $49, but I see it is now $79.

This program is amazing. It's not necessarily fast as it will reread some sectors over and over, trying to get a consensus value from multiple tries, but when it's done you can get back stuff that you thought was gone forever. I had one drive that it took over 10 hours to analyze, but when it was done I got back over 97% of a 500GB drive. Definitely worth the price.

Another great tool is Beyond Compare. I have rev 2.5.3, but it is currently at 3.?? and costs $30. They have a full-functionality, 30-day trail. It does a great job of copying large quantities of files (and only those that need to be copied) and, unlike Explorer, it doesn't blow up if something fails. It's sort of like a visual rsync for Windows, if you're familiar with that program from the Samba people.

I have no connection with either of the comapnies mentioned other than being a very satisfied customer.

Answer (score 0):

The gold standard for recovering data from a magnetic storage device would have to be [SpinRite](http://www.spinrite.info). It's a commerical app though, so you probably wouldn't learn much from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux machine around, I can recommend [dvdisaster](http://dvdisaster.net/en/index.php). It is originally meant for creating error correction files, but it also reads DVDs into an image and ignores read errors; and you can use different drives one after another to get missing sectors filled in the image.